# Show that there are no values of $c$ such that $f(x) = c/x$ can serve as the values of the probability distribution

Tags: statistics

I would appreciate some help with this question:

Show that there are no values of $c$ such that $f(x) = c/x$ can serve as the values of the probability distribution of a random variable with the countably infinite range $x = 1, 2, 3, ...$

So far I have $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} c/x = 1$ so $c\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} 1/x = 1$.

Then I considered $\lim_{x\to\infty} 1/x = 0$.

$c(0) \neq 1$.

Are the last two steps of this correct, namely the limit step and the $c(0) \neq 1$ step? Or are these steps incorrect?

Comment: I don't understand the last two steps.  $c$ is meant to be a constant...what does it mean to evaluate it at $0$? The key issue here is the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1n$.  What do you know about that sum?

Comment: @lulu I am not evaluating at 0, but the summation is 0, so if we multiply c and 0, we must get 1, but there is no way to do this. Is this enough to prove that there are no values of c that work? Is this the correct way to go about solving the question?

Comment: I don;'t understand your argument at all. The fact that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1x=0$ is really not that helpful.

Comment: Ok, thank you @lulu

Answer (score 0):

You need the fact that the harmonic series $\sum_x \frac  1 x$ is divergent. So we cannot have $c$ such that $c \sum_x \frac  1 x=1$.

Comment: Yes, so is the way that I currently showed that correct?

Comment: As mentioned by lulu your argument does not  make sense. @Sparklestheunicorn

Comment: Does simply saying that the sum is divergent enough of an argument? @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @Sparklestheunicorn Yes, becasue for a pmf $(p(x))$ it is necessary that $\sum p(x) =1$ (which implies that $\sum p(x) <\infty$).